# XSD Choice, not the same element again

Tags: xml, xsd

How is it possible to use choice and set that in the group you have to choice minimum 2 elements, but not twice the same element????

Example code:

```
 xs:group name="Ports">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
    <xs:element name="Port1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="PortArguments"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 

    <xs:element name="Port2">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:group ref="PortArguments"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 
    </xs:choice>
```

Another Question: Is it Possible to limit the Access of the Elements in the group?? For Example: I have to other groups. Group 1 should only select element 1-3 of the Ports group. Group 2 should select only Element 1-10 !! How can i realize that?

Comment: Try `xs:all`? I never have, but take a look.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement? May be a sample XML would do with that..

Comment: what did you mean with elaborate your requirement?

Comment: i think xs:all is not right, because it says the element can appear one or zero time. but my requirement is: I have a list with several Ports and i want to define a minimum which should appear. but it should not be possible to select one element twice time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, there is no solution for what you want, for generic cases. You would have to apply Schematron constraints or move to XSD 1.1.